# Отображение флеш ролика через Shockwave Flash Object

Tags: c#, flash

В коде страницы сайта вижу следующий скрипт, который выводит ролик:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window["flash_wnd"] = new Object();
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.lang = encodeURIComponent("rus");
    flashvars.api = encodeURIComponent("http://site.ru/php/site_api.php");
    flashvars.paymentsURL = encodeURIComponent("http://site.ru/xml/pay.php");
    var params = {};
    params.wmode = "window";
    params.bgcolor = "#EFD5A4";
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/my.swf?nc=8", "flash_wnd", "607", "500", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Хочу запустить этот ролик на WindowsForms C#, пишу следующее:

```
string url = "http://site.ru/swf/my.swf?nc=8";
flashPlayer.SetVariable("lang", "rus");
flashPlayer.SetVariable("api", "http://site.ru/php/site_api.php");
flashPlayer.SetVariable("paymentsURL", "http://site.ru/xml/pay.php");
flashPlayer.LoadMovie(0, url);
```

Ролик запускается, но не корректно. В нем идет реклама, а первый кадр это загрузка. Так вот дальше загрузки он не идет, я понимаю, что скорее всего дело в:

> var params = {}; и var attributes = {};

Есть ли идеи, как правильно запустить такой ролик или как передать параметры, неужели это просто массивами добавлять через **SetVariable**?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону параметра "autoplay". Скорее всего в самом SWF ролике не стоит автовоспроизведение. Либо не может что либо подгрузить.

Comment: А возможно, что ролик не подгружается, т.к. flash player не получает куки? Возможно ли передать куки ему вообще? Я попробовал и незарегистрированный пользователь так же не видит данный ролик.